# Understanding $\int_{[0,1)}x^2d\mu=\frac13+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$, where $\mu=m+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\delta_{1/n}$ and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let $m$ be the lebesgue measure in $[0,1)$. We consider the following measure:

$$\mu=m+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\delta_\frac{1}{n},$$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac measure in $1/n$. I don't understand the reason for the result of the following integral:

$$\int_{[0,1)}x^2\; d\mu=\frac{1}{3}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Could someone explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: It's a straightforward consequence of the definition. There is nothing to explain, unless you don't know what $\delta$ is

Comment: $\int fd\delta_c=f(c)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
     \begin{align*}
         \int_{[0, 1)} 1_A d\mu &= \mu(A) = m(A) + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \delta_{1/n}(A)\\
          &= \int_{[0,1)} 1_A dm + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_{[0, 1)} 1_A d\delta_{1/n}
     \end{align*}
$$

Thus, for any positive and measurable function $f$ on $[0, 1)$, we have
$$
      \int_{[0, 1)} f d\mu = \int_{[0, 1)} f dm + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)
$$

where
$$
      \int_{[0, 1)} f d\delta_{1/n} = f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)
$$
Now, apply this with $f(x) = x^2$

Comment: Thanks. Did you use the fact that every measurable function can be approximated by simple functions?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.